# OCSP_basic_verify:signer certificate not found with my own ocsp responder

Tags: openssl, ocsp

I'am developing my own `OCSP` responder.

First, I just want to send an `OCSP` request with `openssl` to my responder and receive a correct answer.

I have a CA certificate `CA.crt` and its son `RC.crt`. I want to check status certificate of `RC.crt`.

My responder signs the response with its own self-signed certificate (OCSPSigning key usage...) caOcsp.pem. (In RFC2560 it is written "The key used to sign the response must belong to one of the following... A trusted Responder whose public key is trusted by the requester ...

So I just do :

```
openssl ocsp -issuer CA.crt -CAfile ..\caOcsp.pem -VAfile ..\caOcsp.pem -cert RC.crt -req_text -url http://localhost:8080/myServlet
```

In openssl documentation :

```
-CAfile file containing trusted certificate there are **used to verify the signature on the ocsp response**  (That's why I put my ocsp certificate)
-VAfile file **containing explicitly trusted responder certificate**  (That's why I put my ocsp certificate too...)

and I got the following response :
 OCSP Request Data:
    Version: 1 (0x0)
    Requestor List:
        Certificate ID:
          Hash Algorithm: sha1
          Issuer Name Hash: 19266539D5B4B518D4382B2D3779CBF53A6061D6
          Issuer Key Hash: 89B91685082EF65F5611F965E94422D602BE27DB
          Serial Number: 0A
    Request Extensions:
        OCSP Nonce:
            0410A75FEC94E252E5BDCA3FDABEEEC56CD7
***Response Verify Failure
7744:error:27069076:OCSP routines:OCSP_basic_verify:signer certificate not found:.\crypto\ocsp\ocsp_vfy.c:85:***

RC.crt: good
        This Update: May 13 08:40:52 2014 GMT
```

What have I forgotten? 
What is wrong?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/), [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my server application I built my OCSPRespBuilder with the right certificate but my responderID  used to create this OCSPRespBuilder was wrong.

Now It works.